# Does latex(describe(...)) work under knitr with MiKTeX?

Tags: latex, knitr, miktex, hmisc

When I create a file describe.Rnw as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<results='asis'>>=
require(Hmisc)
latex(describe(cars), file="")
@


\end{document}
```

and try to compile it with

```
library(knitr)
knit2pdf("describe.Rnw")
```

I get error messages that suggest the latex created by the latex(describe()) combination has grammatical errors:

```
LaTeX errors:
P:/r/ellisp/test/describe.tex:65: LaTeX Error: Environment spacing undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help
Your command was ignored.
P:/r/ellisp/test/describe.tex:131: LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{
spacing}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
```

I can see the latex it has generated, pasted below - something wrong perhaps with the line spacing confusing the parsing?  My whole setup is new (in fact in testing mode) and I'm new to knitr although I've successfully compiled documents, but I don't know whether there may be something wrong with my setup too.  My first question is, am I doing something wrong or is this a more general problem??

```
> latex(describe(cars), file="")
\begin{spacing}{0.7}
\begin{center}\textbf{ cars \\ 2 Variables~~~~~ 50 ~Observations}\end{center}
\smallskip\hrule\smallskip{\small
\vbox{\noindent\textbf{speed}

{\smaller
\begin{tabular}{ rrrrrrrrrrr }
n&missing&unique&Mean&.05&.10&.25&.50&.75&.90&.95 \\
50&0&19&15.4& 7.0& 8.9&12.0&15.0&19.0&23.1&24.0 \end{tabular}

\begin{verbatim}
          4 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 22 23 24 25
Frequency 2 2 1 1  3  2  4  4  4  3  2  3  4  3  5  1  1  4  1
%         4 4 2 2  6  4  8  8  8  6  4  6  8  6 10  2  2  8  2
\end{verbatim}
}
\smallskip\hrule\smallskip
}
\vbox{\noindent\textbf{dist}\setlength{\unitlength}{0.001in}\hfill\begin{picture}(1.5,.1)(1500,0)\linethickness{0.6pt}
\put(0,0){\line(0,1){25}}
\put(15,0){\line(0,1){25}}
\put(90,0){\line(0,1){50}}
\put(150,0){\line(0,1){25}}
\put(165,0){\line(0,1){25}}
\put(180,0){\line(0,1){25}}
\put(195,0){\line(0,1){25}}
\put(225,0){\line(0,1){50}}
\put(240,0){\line(0,1){25}}
\put(270,0){\line(0,1){25}}
\put(300,0){\line(0,1){100}}
\put(330,0){\line(0,1){50}}
\put(375,0){\line(0,1){75}}
\put(405,0){\line(0,1){75}}
\put(420,0){\line(0,1){50}}
\put(480,0){\line(0,1){50}}
\put(495,0){\line(0,1){25}}
\put(555,0){\line(0,1){50}}
\put(570,0){\line(0,1){25}}
\put(600,0){\line(0,1){25}}
\put(630,0){\line(0,1){25}}
\put(660,0){\line(0,1){50}}
\put(675,0){\line(0,1){50}}
\put(735,0){\line(0,1){25}}
\put(780,0){\line(0,1){25}}
\put(810,0){\line(0,1){25}}
\put(825,0){\line(0,1){25}}
\put(855,0){\line(0,1){25}}
\put(930,0){\line(0,1){25}}
\put(990,0){\line(0,1){25}}
\put(1035,0){\line(0,1){25}}
\put(1050,0){\line(0,1){25}}
\put(1140,0){\line(0,1){25}}
\put(1155,0){\line(0,1){25}}
\put(1485,0){\line(0,1){25}}
\end{picture}

{\smaller
\begin{tabular}{ rrrrrrrrrrr }
n&missing&unique&Mean&.05&.10&.25&.50&.75&.90&.95 \\
50&0&35&42.98&10.00&15.80&26.00&36.00&56.00&80.40&88.85 \end{tabular}
\begin{verbatim}
lowest :   2   4  10  14  16, highest:  84  85  92  93 120 
\end{verbatim}
}
\smallskip\hrule\smallskip
}
}\end{spacing}
```

Here's my session info:

> sessionInfo()
>       R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
>       Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

```
locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_New Zealand.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_New Zealand.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_New Zealand.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                        
[5] LC_TIME=English_New Zealand.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] splines   graphics  datasets  grid      stats     grDevices utils    
[8] methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] x12_1.1-0        tseries_0.10-32  stringr_0.6.2    lubridate_1.3.0 
 [5] tables_0.7       Hmisc_3.12-2     Formula_1.1-1    survival_2.37-4 
 [9] stargazer_4.0    knitr_1.2        proto_0.3-10     extrafont_0.14  
[13] Defaults_1.1-1   scales_0.2.3     reshape2_1.2.2   plyr_1.8        
[17] ggplot2_0.9.3.1  foreign_0.8-53   mvtnorm_0.9-9995

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] cluster_1.14.4     codetools_0.2-8    colorspace_1.2-2   dichromat_2.0-0   
 [5] digest_0.6.3       evaluate_0.4.4     formatR_0.9        gtable_0.1.2      
 [9] labeling_0.2       lattice_0.20-15    MASS_7.3-27        munsell_0.4.2     
[13] quadprog_1.5-5     RColorBrewer_1.0-5 rpart_4.1-1        Rttf2pt1_1.2      
[17] tools_3.0.1        zoo_1.7-10
```

Edit - here is the describe.tex document created by knitr.

```
\documentclass{article}\usepackage{graphicx, color}
%% maxwidth is the original width if it is less than linewidth
%% otherwise use linewidth (to make sure the graphics do not exceed the margin)
\makeatletter
\def\maxwidth{ %
  \ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth
    \linewidth
  \else
    \Gin@nat@width
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\definecolor{fgcolor}{rgb}{0.2, 0.2, 0.2}
\newcommand{\hlnumber}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlfunctioncall}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.501960784313725,0,0.329411764705882}{\textbf{#1}}}%
\newcommand{\hlstring}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.6,0.6,1}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlkeyword}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{\textbf{#1}}}%
\newcommand{\hlargument}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.690196078431373,0.250980392156863,0.0196078431372549}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlcomment}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.180392156862745,0.6,0.341176470588235}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlroxygencomment}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.43921568627451,0.47843137254902,0.701960784313725}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlformalargs}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.690196078431373,0.250980392156863,0.0196078431372549}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hleqformalargs}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.690196078431373,0.250980392156863,0.0196078431372549}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlassignement}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{\textbf{#1}}}%
\newcommand{\hlpackage}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.588235294117647,0.709803921568627,0.145098039215686}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlslot}[1]{\textit{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlsymbol}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlprompt}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.2,0.2,0.2}{#1}}%

\usepackage{framed}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{kframe}{%
 \def\at@end@of@kframe{}%
 \ifinner\ifhmode%
  \def\at@end@of@kframe{\end{minipage}}%
  \begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}%
 \fi\fi%
 \def\FrameCommand##1{\hskip\@totalleftmargin \hskip-\fboxsep
 \colorbox{shadecolor}{##1}\hskip-\fboxsep
     % There is no \\@totalrightmargin, so:
     \hskip-\linewidth \hskip-\@totalleftmargin \hskip\columnwidth}%
 \MakeFramed {\advance\hsize-\width
   \@totalleftmargin\z@ \linewidth\hsize
   \@setminipage}}%
 {\par\unskip\endMakeFramed%
 \at@end@of@kframe}
\makeatother

\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{.97, .97, .97}
\definecolor{messagecolor}{rgb}{0, 0, 0}
\definecolor{warningcolor}{rgb}{1, 0, 1}
\definecolor{errorcolor}{rgb}{1, 0, 0}
\newenvironment{knitrout}{}{} % an empty environment to be redefined in TeX

\usepackage{alltt}
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{kframe}
\begin{alltt}
\hlfunctioncall{require}(Hmisc)
\hlfunctioncall{latex}(\hlfunctioncall{describe}(cars), file = \hlstring{""})
\end{alltt}
\end{kframe}\begin{spacing}{0.7}
\begin{center}\textbf{ cars \\ 2 Variables~~~~~ 50 ~Observations}\end{center}
\smallskip\hrule\smallskip{\small
\vbox{\noindent\textbf{speed}

{\smaller
\begin{tabular}{ rrrrrrrrrrr }
n&missing&unique&Mean&.05&.10&.25&.50&.75&.90&.95 \\
50&0&19&15.4& 7.0& 8.9&12.0&15.0&19.0&23.1&24.0 \end{tabular}

\begin{verbatim}
          4 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 22 23 24 25
Frequency 2 2 1 1  3  2  4  4  4  3  2  3  4  3  5  1  1  4  1
%         4 4 2 2  6  4  8  8  8  6  4  6  8  6 10  2  2  8  2
\end{verbatim}
}
\smallskip\hrule\smallskip
}
\vbox{\noindent\textbf{dist}\setlength{\unitlength}{0.001in}\hfill\begin{picture}(1.5,.1)(1500,0)\linethickness{0.6pt}
\put(0,0){\line(0,1){25}}
\put(15,0){\line(0,1){25}}
\put(90,0){\line(0,1){50}}
\put(150,0){\line(0,1){25}}
\put(165,0){\line(0,1){25}}
\put(180,0){\line(0,1){25}}
\put(195,0){\line(0,1){25}}
\put(225,0){\line(0,1){50}}
\put(240,0){\line(0,1){25}}
\put(270,0){\line(0,1){25}}
\put(300,0){\line(0,1){100}}
\put(330,0){\line(0,1){50}}
\put(375,0){\line(0,1){75}}
\put(405,0){\line(0,1){75}}
\put(420,0){\line(0,1){50}}
\put(480,0){\line(0,1){50}}
\put(495,0){\line(0,1){25}}
\put(555,0){\line(0,1){50}}
\put(570,0){\line(0,1){25}}
\put(600,0){\line(0,1){25}}
\put(630,0){\line(0,1){25}}
\put(660,0){\line(0,1){50}}
\put(675,0){\line(0,1){50}}
\put(735,0){\line(0,1){25}}
\put(780,0){\line(0,1){25}}
\put(810,0){\line(0,1){25}}
\put(825,0){\line(0,1){25}}
\put(855,0){\line(0,1){25}}
\put(930,0){\line(0,1){25}}
\put(990,0){\line(0,1){25}}
\put(1035,0){\line(0,1){25}}
\put(1050,0){\line(0,1){25}}
\put(1140,0){\line(0,1){25}}
\put(1155,0){\line(0,1){25}}
\put(1485,0){\line(0,1){25}}
\end{picture}

{\smaller
\begin{tabular}{ rrrrrrrrrrr }
n&missing&unique&Mean&.05&.10&.25&.50&.75&.90&.95 \\
50&0&35&42.98&10.00&15.80&26.00&36.00&56.00&80.40&88.85 \end{tabular}
\begin{verbatim}
lowest :   2   4  10  14  16, highest:  84  85  92  93 120 
\end{verbatim}
}
\smallskip\hrule\smallskip
}
}\end{spacing}





\end{document}
```

Comment: Your LaTeX file needs an `\end{document}`, but that's obvious from the error.

Comment: Thanks @Werner but there is an \end{document} in the original describe.Rnw, and it survived to describe.tex.  I've edited the question to include the full describe.tex file created by knitr.  The problem seems to me likely to do with a \begin{...} command that isn't recognised for some reason and hence the \begin{} and end{} commands get out of synch.

Comment: If `spacing` is undefined, you should add the [`setspace`](http://ctan.org/pkg/setspace) package to your preamble.

Comment: ok, thanks.  I'll have to try that on another machine as our test environment doesn't have it installed and users don't have rights to add packages (although it is on the much longer list of packages we've asked to be included in the next phase of testing).  Is there somewhere I could have looked up that error message to give me a clue which package was missing?

Comment: Yes, that fixed it in my other environment where I have permissions to install packages.  If you want to make your second comment an answer I'll upvote it and give it the tick (if you could mention how you knew that was the problem too so I know how to find out next time something similar happens that would be great).

Comment: The only reason I know is because I use LaTeX a lot. And there are some packages that could be considered the *de facto* source for certain things: line-spacing = [`setspace`](http://ctan.org/pkg/setspace), lists = [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem), hyper-linking = [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref), ... In this particular instance, there is some information regarding `setspace` [when you Google it](https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=LaTeX+spacing+environment).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the `spacing` environment is undefined, add

```
\usepackage{setspace}
```

to your preamble, since [`setspace`](http://ctan.org/pkg/setspace) defines `spacing`.